# Is there simple xpath to find all parent elements within the xml structure?

Tags: python, xml, xpath

I'm using python 3 and lxml.etree and I need to get list of all parent elements for selected element with the defined name.

Here is example of my XML structure

```
<root>
    <father id="1">
         <father id="2">
              <child>
               ....
```

I do have an  element object and need list of all objects of   (to get their id attributes for example)

Using

```
element.xpath("parent::father)
```

returns list where is only first parent object (father id = 2) but I'd need to have whole path up, regardless how deep I'm.

Thanks

Comment: So you're trying to access all the nodes?  Use XPath: `//*`

Comment: You probably want  `ancestor::*` or if you wan to include the current element `ancestor-or-self:*`

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 , this is definitely not what OP is looking for as `//*` will return simply *all the nodes in DOM*, but not *all ancestors of particular node*

Comment: @chrisis , consider to post the same as answer

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,

@chrisis provided right answer. Probably due to my poor English language skill I didn't realize that `parent::` in real life (and this case ;-) is usually just one level above me, meanwhile element (and I) can have many `ancestor::` (even if the keyword here is not plural ;-)

I just need to check if all ancestor elements are *father* but as `element.xpath("ancestor::*)` returns a list, it's just an easy check.

Thanks a lot.